# SDHC vs SDXC cards for Linux

Tags: sd-card, file-format, exfat

I recently bought a Zenbook prime of 128GB and I bought a [microSD to SD adapter for macbook air](http://www.ebay.com/itm/221365605552) (because of the low profile). It's working great with my SDHC that I had on the phone. I'm thinking about buying [this microSD card](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B009QZH6JS). However, is SDXC supported in Linux? and is SDHC fully supported? Now I know it just works, but which one is preferred for Linux?

The speed is not that important since it's mainly for music, documents and pictures (programs and videos will be in the main SSD).

As we're on it, would higher capacity, like [128GB micro SDXC](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00IIJ6W4S) make any difference? If I buy any of them, I will write about them here, but I wanted to know if anyone had experience on microSDXC or read any review on these cards. I couldn't find anything relevant about Linux/Ubuntu.

According to [Sandisk website](http://kb.sandisk.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/2520/~/sd%2Fsdhc%2Fsdxc-specifications-and-compatibility), the differences are:

- SDHC capacities range from 4GB to 32GB

  Default Format: FAT32
- SDXC capacities range from 64GB to 2TB

  Default Format: exFAT

  The [section about operating systems that support exFAT File System](http://kb.sandisk.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/3389/session/L2F2LzEvdGltZS8xMzkzNTk0NjYyL3NpZC91ckRhaTNPbA%3D%3D) does not even mention Linux. Furthermore, I'm interested about **exFAT on SD cards**, not about [simple exFAT support on Linux](http://news.softpedia.com/news/Native-exFAT-Support-Finally-Arrives-on-Linux-365770.shtml), in case they differ.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have an SDXC card or a compatible reader, but I would advise caution if you are planning to use exFAT as it doesn't work for me on Lubuntu 13.10. I formatted on Windows 8, a 4gb usb stick in exFAT with 4096 allocation and MBR partition table. I wasn't able to mount it on Lubuntu 13.10. Additionally gparted only lists being able to copy and move exFAT partitions, not create them which could be a problem should you ever need to reformat the card. I have successfully used 32gb SDHC cards in Ubuntu before formatted as NTFS and FAT32 without any problems.

Screenshot of mount attempt of 4gb usb stick using exFAT:

[image: Screenshot of mount attempt of 4gb usb stick using exFAT]

Screenshot of Gparted filesystem support:

[image: Screenshot of Gparted filesystem support]

Answer (score 2):

Install the support for exFAT and you won't have a problem with it:

```
sudo apt-get install exfat-utils
```

Comment: But `exfat-utils` does not have good documentation, could you please mention some example usage of this utility: e.g. how to format card using this utility?

Comment: Hi PHP Learner, use Gparted like in the example above. GParted deals with it itself.